# Elasticsearch multiple index query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a following index which stores the course details (I have truncated some attributes for brevity):

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "number_of_shards": "1"
    }
  },
  "aliases": {
    "course": {
      
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "max_per_user": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here max_per_user is number of times a user can complete the course. A user is allowed through a course multiple times but not more than max_per_user for a course
I want to track user interactions with courses. I have created following index to track interaction events. event_type_id represents a type of interaction

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "number_of_shards": "1"
    }
  },
  "aliases": {
    "course_events": {
      
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_progress": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {
          "current_count": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "user_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "events": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {
              "event_type_id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "event_timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_time"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_time"
      },
      "course_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where current_count is number of times the user has gone through the complete course

Now when I run a search on course index, I also want to be able to pass in the user_id and get only those courses where the current_count for the given user is less than max_per_user for the course

My search query for course index is something like this (truncated some filters for brevity). This query is executed when a user searches for a course, so basically at the time of executing this I will have user_id.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "end_date": {
              "gte": "2020-09-28T12:27:55.884Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "start_date": {
              "lte": "2020-09-28T12:27:55.884Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "is_active": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to construct my search query such that I am able to filter out courses where max_per_user has been achieved for a given user_id.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly you want to find the courses where max_per_user limit isn't exceeded. My answer is on the same basis:

**Considering your current Schema way to find what you want is:**

1. For the given user_id find all the course_ids and their corresponding completion count
2. Using the data fetched in #1 find out the courses where-in max_per_user limit is not exceeded.

**Now comes the problem**:

1. In a relational database such use case can be solved using table join and checks
2. Elastic Search doesn't support joins and can't be done here.

**Poor solution with current schema:**

1. For each course check whether it is applicable or not. For n courses number of queries to E.S will be proportional to N.

**Solution with current schema:**

1. With-in the user-course-completion index (second index you mentioned), track max_per_user as well and use a simple query like below, to get the required course ids :

   ```
    {
     "size": 10,
     "query": {
       "script": {
          "script": "doc['current_usage'].value<doc['max_per_user'].value && 
          doc['u_id'].value==1" // <======= 1 is the user_id here
   }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: You have the liberty to change the schema here? For.e.g rather than maintaining 2 different indices, resort to parent-child relationship with-in the same index?

Comment: I can do that, but then I read this `

index.mapping.nested_objects.limit
    The maximum number of nested JSON objects that a single document can contain across all nested types. This limit helps to prevent out of memory errors when a document contains too many nested objects. Default is 10000. ` in ES documentation and got worried about memory issues in my main index (course index)

Comment: You checked the solution I provided?

Comment: Yes, so basically I will call ES _search API twice. In 1st call I will get all courses from course index and in second call(your solution) I will get all courses valid for the user and then filter it out in memory. Right?

Comment: "Solution with current schema"  is what I am talking about. With that one query on second index would be required to fetch either applicable/not-applicable course_id for the given user,which can then be used to fetch courses from the first index

Comment: I tried that and its giving me an error  `No field found for [user_progress.current_usage] in mapping with types []`

Comment: I have created a parent child relationship now, but not sure how to construct my search query. I have provided details in this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141478/elastic-search-parent-child-query

Comment: I've tried the same thing myself but I haven't found a way to compare the parent & child doc attribute hence didn't recommend. The best approach i figured out is already mentioned in "Solution using current schema"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222321/discussion-between-sahil-gupta-and-prim).